# what if the square of a martingale is still a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales, local-martingales

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t:t\ge{0}),P)$ be a stochastic basis and $M=(M_t:t\ge{0})$ a locally square integrable martingale, which means a stochastic process such that:

- $M_t\in{L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F_t},P)}$ for all $t\ge{0};$
- $\mathbb{E}[M_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=M_s$ for all $t\ge{s}$.

Show that, if $M^2$ is a locally integrable martingale, then $M_t=M_0$ for all $t\ge{0}$; which means the martingale is constant.

I know that in this case $M^2$ is a submartingale and $M^2-[M,M]$ is a martingale, where $[M,M]$ indicates the quadratic variation, but I don't know how to use this to prove the statement.

Comment: As quadratic variation is an increasing process that means that it is constant, so what happens to a process which has constant quadratic variation ?

Comment: I'll try, does that mean $[M,M]_t=[M,M]_0=0$ for all $t\ge{0}$? In this case I get $M_t=0$ for all $t\ge{0}$. But why should the quadratic variation be constant?

Comment: Well you can't be increasing and martingale at the same time right unless your constant ? because M^2 and M^2-<M> are martingales then <M> is also a martingale (martingale is linear space)

Comment: You can look at Protter's book there is a theorem that states that a martingale (local?) and its quadratic variations have a.s. the same intervals of "constancy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M$ and $M^2$ are martingales, for any $t\geq s\geq 0$ holds:
$$\mathbb{E}[M_t^2] = \mathbb{E}[M_s^2]=\mathbb{V}[M_s^2]+\mathbb{E}[M_s]^2=\mathbb{V}[M_s^2]+\mathbb{E}[M_t]^2.$$
Substracting $\mathbb{E}[M_t]^2$ from both sides yields
$$\mathbb{V}[M_s^2]=0.$$
Thus
$$\mathbb{V}[M_s^2]=\mathbb{E}[(M_s-\mathbb{E}[M_s])^2]=0.$$
Since $(M_s-\mathbb{E}[M_s])^2$ is non-negative and its excpeted value is zero, it has to be zero almost everywhere:
$$(M_s-\mathbb{E}[M_s])^2=0\quad \text{a.e.},$$
resulting in
$$M_s=\mathbb{E}[M_s]\quad \text{a.e.},$$
indicating that $M_s$ has to be constant. And
$$M_t=\mathbb{E}[M_t]=\mathbb{E}[M_0]=M_0.$$